# RDL report - Chart with both bar and lines

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

I want to show in one chart report two series of data, one as a horizontal bar and one as a line. When I select for the second series a line chart type, it changes also the chart type for the first series which was set to bars.

This works if I'm using vertical columns for the first series, but it seems it is not working the same with horizontal bars.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cannot create a chart with horizontal bars and lines.

- SSRS doesnt allow it.
- It is **not logical** to join two concepts which is transpose of each
  other. It is like showing vertical bar chart and horizontal bar chart
  in the same graph.
- Line charts are used to show overall trends and
  patterns over time(usually) or some other series. Bar charts are good
  for comparing unordered/nominal items.

You need to reevaluate your decision to show these two together.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The need for horizontal bars is due to layout of the report (small width and lot of categories). I'll try other approaches.